# XML Layout Inflation Failing for Listview

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview

I've been trying to get this custom xml layout for a listview with a custom adapter to work (render) forever. No errors are being thrown, the top textview just refuses to render (i checked in the android device manager).
I've also debugged it  at the getView function, and made sure the object list was correctly populated, and that findviewbyid on the textview worked.

Heres the xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="5dp"
android:background="@drawable/itembackground">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/itemicon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemtopLine"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/itembotLine"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/itemicon"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/itembotLine"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/itemicon"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

heres the adapter

```
public class SpaceAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SpaceItem>{
     public SpaceAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<SpaceItem>       items) {
    super(context, resource, items);
     }

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null){
        v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.space_item, null);
    }

    SpaceItem item = getItem(position);

    ImageView icon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.itemicon);
    TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.itemtopLine);
    TextView prop = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.itembotLine);

    if (item != null){
        icon.setImageDrawable(item.spaceItemIcon);
        name.setText(item.spaceItemName);
        prop.setText(item.spaceItemDescription);
    }
    else {
        icon.setImageDrawable(getContext().getResources()
                                          .getDrawable(android.R.drawable.btn_star, null));
        name.setText("Default");
        name.setText("kek");
    }

    return v;
}
}
```

here's the item

```
public class SpaceItem {
    public Drawable spaceItemIcon;
    public String spaceItemName;
    public String spaceItemDescription;
    public SpaceItem (Drawable ico, String name, String d){
        spaceItemDescription = d;
        spaceItemIcon = ico;
        spaceItemName = name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your SpaceItem code?

Comment: It's the adapter. The problem is almost always in the adapter. Can you post it?

Comment: are you trying to have the image View to the left and both text Views to right one on top and the other on the bottom, if so, try to set a width for the image view, say 100dp, and change both text Views width to match_parent and see if that helps

Comment: The ImageView is your background for item?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I figured out the problem.  turns out my layout inflation method not be using the two parameter constructor with null.  I still don't know why that would cause the top view to disappear though.